# media control "resume" and "pause" via NFC tag do not work

Tags: lineageos, android-10, music, nfc, samsung-galaxy-a3

## Problem description

I wrote tasks onto NFC tags

- to play different playlists in a media player app,
- to control the media player (Vol +/-, next/previous title, pause/resume, quit media player) and
- to shut down the smartphone.

Starting the media player playing a certain playlist works fine. All media control commands/tasks **work fine except for "pause", "resume" and "pause/resume"**. Quitting the media player (with root permissions) and shutting down the smartphone work.

**The smartphone recognizes these commands/tasks** and prints them to the display when a NFC tag with one of these commands written onto it is held onto the smartphone's NFC reader. However, the **currently running music is not paused and paused music is not resumed**. There is no difference between running the media player in the background or in the foreground.

## Question

What might cause this issue and how can I solve it?

## Technical Details

- **OS:** Lineage OS 17.1 official (Android 10)
- **device:** Galaxy A3 2016
- **media player app:** VLC Media player (but also tested Foldplay, Vanilla Music, mMusic Mini, Audify Music, AOSP Music+, Schlichter Music-Player, Simple Music Player, Lineage OS Music Player 3.0).
- **NFC Writer Apps:** MacroDroid (root permissions), NFC Tools PRO (default user permissions)
- **tried these NFC tag writers as well** (but they could not write *media control* commands onto NFC tags)**:** NFC TagWrite by NXP, NFC Writer by Trigger, NFC/RF Reader and Write (by GreenlifeiInfo Tech), NFC-Tags write and read (by Yalintech), NFC Tag Writer & Reader (by Winning Studios Apps)
- can be **reproduced** on **same smartphone model** with **Lineage OS 19.1 unofficial** (Android 12) without any root permissions

## Some other details

I am setting up a "music box" for my child similar to a [Tony Box](https://tonies.com/en-gb/) based on a Galaxy A3 2016. This music box should be controlable by NFC tags - except for turning the smartphone on. Most tasks are written via the MacroDroid App which has root priviledges. "pause/resume" neither works when written via MacroDroid (root) nor when written via NFC Tasks Pro (without root priviledges).

The display briefly flickers if a "media control pause/resume/pause-or-resume" command/task is issued via a NFC tag. But, nothing else happens except ... [see next paragraph].

If I play an audio file in the LineageOS Music Player by tabbing onto the file in the file browser, a minimal version of the player appears. If I hold a "media control: pause" tag onto the smartphone's NFC readern then the app is killed. However, this does not happen when I start the LineageOS mediaplayer manually and start playing audio files from within the player. This happens with no other player.

/edit:

## What I tried so far to solved this issue

- tried nine different music players
- looked for (and tried) different NFC writer apps; however, most of the NFC writer apps do not allow writing media control tasks
- searched via my favorite search machine for my problem:

  - the search results are related to old problems more then five years ago and, hence, target old android versions
  - often all media control commands are affected
  - only some apps are affected (e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/d43kt0/help_media_control_toggle_pause_not_working_on/))
- tried another version of LineageOS
- tried a smartphone with a freshly installed OS

Comment: You could raise this issue in MacroDroid forums too alternatively try with Tasker to rule out automation issues (I neither use NFC nor Tasker but it may be worth a check) +1 for a detailed homework

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks for the positive comment. I'll check out Tasker.